# Insert a calculated column into a Dataframe (with a strange column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my problem is the following:
i have a dataframe like this

| item | x |
| --- | --- |
| blabla | [{key1: value1}] |
| blable | [{key2: value2] |

ok i would like to add a column with the value in the dict, inside the list.

| item | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| blabla | [{key1: value1}] | value1 |
| blable | [{key1: value2] | value2 |

I have tried this:

```
df= df_list['mydf'].assign(y = (df_list['mydf']['x'])[0]['key1'] )
```

note: i have a list of dataframe, df_list, because they will be merged with concat

but [0] seems to get only the value of the first row:

```
 [{key1: value1}]
```

you can try with this dummy df:

```
df_test = {'a': pd.DataFrame({'item': ['blabla', 'blable'], 'x': [[{'a':1}],[{'a':2}] ]}), 'b': pd.DataFrame({'item': ['bl', 'le'], 'x': [[{'a':3}],[{'a':4}] ]}) }

df_test['a'].assign(y = df_test['a']['item']+"0")
```

output:

| / | item | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | blabla | [{'a': 1}] | blabla0 |
| 1 | blable | [{'a': 2}] | blable0 |

```
df_test['a'].assign(y = df_test['a']['x'][0])
```

output

```
Length of values (1) does not match length of index (2)
```

when the expected value should be the dict. I really cant understand what pd is trying to do

Thanks!

Comment: Why did `key2` change to `key1`?

Comment: You're overcomplicating the question by wrapping the df in a dictionary. That dictionary is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: this was an example to play around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a lambda function? Indexing ["x"][0] won't work because pandas will just take the [0] index as the first element of that column. The lambda function will return x[0]["a"] on input x which is a singular element in the dataframe. this works:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['blabla', 'blable'], 'x': [[{'a':1}],[{'a':2}] ]})
df["y"] = df["x"].apply(lambda x: x[0]["a"])
print(df)
```

```
     item           x  y
0  blabla  [{'a': 1}]  1
1  blable  [{'a': 2}]  2
```

Comment: instaresolved the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.explode()` to extract the element of the list.

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'item': ['blabla', 'blable'], 'x': [[{'a':1}],[{'a':2}] ]})
df['y'] = df['x'].explode().str['a']
print(df)
```

produces

```
     item           x  y
0  blabla  [{'a': 1}]  1
1  blable  [{'a': 2}]  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use df.apply() to apply a lambda function to the column.

Your example dataframe:

```py
df = {'a': pd.DataFrame({'item': ['blabla', 'blable'], 'x': [[{'a':1}],[{'a':2}] ]}), 'b': pd.DataFrame({'item': ['bl', 'le'], 'x': [[{'a':3}],[{'a':4}] ]}) }
df['a']
```

output:

| item | x |
| --- | --- |
| blabla | [{'a': 1}] |
| blable | [{'a': 2}] |

Using .apply() and lambda:

```py
df['a']['y'] = df['a'].x.apply(lambda x: x[0]['a']) # get the value for key 'a' in first dict in list
df['a']
```

output:

| item | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| blabla | [{'a': 1}] | 1 |
| blable | [{'a': 2}] | 2 |